# Different output wkhtmltopdf local and on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

On my Macbook I have `wkhtmltopdf` installed and when I do `wkhtmltopdf -V` I get:

`wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)`

When I deploy the Rails app to Heroku, the PDF renders different. So I checked the version on Heroku with `heroku run "wkhtmltopdf -V"`, but that gives me:

`bash: wkhtmltopdf: command not found`.

The PDF itself renders fine on Heroku, so there must be a `wkhtmltopdf` installed I guess? I followed these instructions to create a buildpack, but with no change when I request the version:

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/rafaelp/heroku-buildpack-wkhtmltopdf

In the `Gemfile` I have this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '~> 0.12.2.1'
end
```

So, how do I properly install `wkhtmltopdf` on Heroku and make sure the version is the same as on my Macbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably seeing a conflict in versions here between a binary bundled in the gem you're using in development, and another binary.

You should manually manage your wkhtmltopdf binary manually in development & heroku (homebrew/apt-get + buildpack), or use a gem which includes the binaries in both environments. Not a mix of both, as you'll get inconsistent results.

Personally, I use this [buildpack](https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack) on heroku and use brew to install the version I need locally for development.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this too to sync both versions!